# Firefox: how to show local image with relative path

Tags: firefox

I want to put an image with relative path to local file.

Firefox doesn't seem to accept something like

```
<img src=images/test.gif>
```

What's the syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<img src="./images/test.gif" />
```

but have you checked that the image exists at that location?